# Un-UNIQUE column mysql

Tags: mysql, unique, alter

I need to change a column which is unique to not being unique in mysql. Im sure someone out there can help me with this easy one.

Comment: Please paste your table definition into your question. You'll need to redesign your table if it is the primary key you wish to make non-unique.

Comment: drop index is very common syntex, have not you googled it?

Answer (score 6):

A unique contraint on a column in MySQL is implemented as a unique index on that column. To remove the constraint simply drop the index.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP INDEX index_name
```

To see the names of the indexes on a table use [SHOW INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html).

```
SHOW INDEX FROM yourtable
```

Comment: You may want to create a normal index in its place, for instance if you are querying against the column.